# Quasi-regular elements which are not in the Jacobson radical

Tags: abstract-algebra, commutative-algebra

Suppose $R$ is a commutative ring. An element $x \in R$ is called quasi-regular if $1-x$ is a unit. Are there examples of $R$ and $x$ such that $x$ is quasi-regular, but $yx$ is not, for some $y \in R$? In other words, examples of quasi-regular $x$ which is not in the Jacobson radical of $R$.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Take $R=\mathbb{Z}$ and $x=2$.

Comment: Thanks! The idea is to start with units and construct $x$, that can be done in many examples...